# Send data to socket on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets

I don't know very much about sockets at all. What I am wondering is how the sockets work.

1) Firewalls often block ports. Is it plausible that if I request a socket and it is behind a blocked port anything that is sent or received will get intercepted and destroyed? Is this an issue?

2) On the server side how do you keep the connection alive to send data back through, like if I was building a chat app is it possible to start a connection through a socket and keep that alive and have the server basically push new data through the stream. Instead of the apps having to query every so often.

3) If the app goes into the background apple says they will keep the socket as long its not needed (if it is voip). Does that mean that I could still send data through to the app and have it handled? If my app is registered for location updates and executing in the background already will the socket stay open?

Are there any server languages that make it simple? I am currently using python and Django for a simple http server. Are any tutorials on setting up a server that can keep connections alive. I really don't know much about this so what i'm asking may not make any sense but some direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I haven't found an issue with firewalls at all.

2) I used a twisted server along side my web server  to implement a event driven socket server and it works great.

3) the sockets will stay open as long as you are executing in the background and the delegate methods are called to handle stream events.

There is an excellent tutorial here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

that goes over the twisted framework and how to create a chat app with sockets. I found that immensely helpful.

Comment: Why dont you provide the link with your answer ? I am sure some people would love that.